Plotting a decision boundary separating 2 classes
I could use a tip to help me plot a decision boundary to separate classes of data. I created some sample data via Python NumPy. In this case, every data point is a 2D coordinate, but every time I try plotting it  using my code it won't plot
I don't know how to make it plot even thou I used multiple adjustments to the code??
import pandas as pd import numpy as np from pathlib import Path

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import seaborn as sns import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DATA_HOME = Path("/content/assignment1.csv")

df = pd.read_csv(DATA_HOME)

print(df.info()) print(df.describe())

print(df.isnull().sum())

sns.pairplot(df, hue="label", diag_kind="kde") plt.title('Pairplot of Features') plt.show()

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2) X_poly = poly.fit_transform(df[['x', 'y']])

y = df['label']

scaler = StandardScaler() X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_poly)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

best_accuracy = 0 best_logreg_model = None best_logreg_params = {}

for penalty in ['l1', 'l2']: for C in [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]: # Train logistic regression model model = LogisticRegression(C=C, penalty=penalty, solver='liblinear', random_state=42) model.fit(X_train, y_train)   
 # Evaluate model on test set
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    
    # Check if current model is the best so far
    if accuracy > best_accuracy:
        best_accuracy = accuracy
        best_logreg_model = model
        best_logreg_params = {'C': C, 'penalty': penalty}
y_pred_full_logreg = best_logreg_model.predict(X_scaled) accuracy_full_logreg = accuracy_score(y, y_pred_full_logreg)

print("Best hyperparameters for Logistic Regression:", best_logreg_params) print("Accuracy on full dataset for Logistic Regression:", accuracy_full_logreg)



if X_poly.shape[1] == 3:  # Only plot if data is 2-dimensional after polynomial transformation 
h = .02 
x_min, x_max = X_scaled[:, 1].min() - 1, X_scaled[:, 1].max() + 1 y_min, 
y_max = X_scaled[:, 2].min() - 1, X_scaled[:, 2].max() + 1 xx, 
yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

# Transform meshgrid coordinates to polynomial features
mesh_data = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]
mesh_poly = poly.transform(mesh_data)

# Predict the classes for meshgrid points
Z = best_logreg_model.predict(mesh_poly)

Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure()
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu, alpha=0.8)

plt.scatter(X_scaled[:, 1], X_scaled[:, 2], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu, edgecolor='k', s=20)
plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.title("Decision Boundary for Logistic Regression with Polynomial Features")
plt.xlabel("Feature 1")
plt.ylabel("Feature 2")
plt.show()
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report print("\nClassification Report:") print(classification_report(y, best_logreg_model.predict(X_scaled)))

